# autorefreshing swf calling data from XML file

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

So i need to make an application witch is calling some data from XMl file. The XML data is going to be dynamic so i need to make an auto refresh in my swf. I've tried this

```
var interval = setInterval(my_function, 10000);
```

because i have

```
my_xml = new XML();

my_xml.load("direktno.xml");

my_xml.onLoad = my_function;

my_xml.ignoreWhite = true;

function my_function()
{ my function }
```

But this only refreshes `my_function` 
without reloading the XML file. Any ideas>

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change you code into this, it reloads the XML file every 10s.

```
var my_xml = new XML();
my_xml.ignoreWhite = true;
my_xml.onLoad = onXMLLoaded;

function reloadXML(){ 
    my_xml.load("direktno.xml");
}
function onXMLLoaded() { 
    // do what you want
}

var interval = setInterval(reloadXML, 10000);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you tell me which part is not working ? I haven't used AS2 for years, so I don't clearly remember, but you might have to create a new XML object each time you want to load the file.

Comment: I did it :) I've just loaded `my_xml.load("direktno.xml");`